# PHP Function Scope Issue

Tags: php, mysqli

Having problems with the scope of variables in functions, the code is more than this but i've tried to simplify to be able to easily explain the problem.

```
<?php
//simply connecting to a database with mysqli
$server='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';
$database='mydatabase';

$mylink = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database);

// a simple function to add two fields to a table
function addpost($userid, $post){
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post) VALUES ('$userid', '$post')";
$result = mysqli_query($mylink, $sql;
echo "done";
}

//assign values to be inserted into the table
$userid = 4;
$followerid = "This is the post";
//call the function and pass arguements
add_post($userid, $followerid);

?>
```

I repeatedly got the following errors

> Notice: Undefined variable: mylink in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\xyz.php
>   on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\xyz.php on line 13

The problem is apparently that the addpost function does not know about $mylink. I can obviously simply move the code to connect to the database into the function but I think that cannot be the right way to go about it. What am I doing wrong? Thnks in advance for ur help

Comment: Make sure to post the *actual* code for an *accurate* test-case: eg. add_follower is called, but addpost is shown. The code also contains invalid syntax and will not parse. Including dubious code does little to establish an accurate (or trust-worthy) test-case.

Comment: Remember to 'Accept' an answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

```
// a simple function to add two fields to a table
function addpost($userid, $post){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post) VALUES ('$userid', '$post')";
  $result = mysqli_query($mylink, $sql);
  echo "done";
}
```

Your problem is with this function. The `function` keyword effectively says to the interpreter that 'here is a piece of code I want to name for use later'. Code inside this function is ignorant of variables declared outside the function.

Because `$mylink` is declared no where in this function, when you attempt to use it, php substitutes `null`. The function you're calling, `mysqli_query`, won't accept a `null` input for the first parameter.

There are two ways around this, the first is to add `$mylink` as a parameter to this function and pass it in. Alternatively, you can use the `global` keyword (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)), though this tends to lead to spaghetti code.

```
function addpost($userid, $post, $mylink){
   //your code
}

addPost($userid, $post, $mylink);
```

Or:

```
function addpost($userid, $post){
  global $mylink;
    //your code
}
```

This latter is considered brittle because there is no obvious connection between this function and what it relies on (a globally declared variable of a particular name). Further, you can run into namespace issues (suppose two places modify something called `$mylink`; can you easily reason about which will be extent when your function is called?).

Comment: PHP most certain supports global variables.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't.

Comment: passing $mylink as a parameter to the addpost function worked, thnks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the $mylink into the function as an argument.

```
$server='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';
$database='mydatabase';

$mylink = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database);

// a simple function to add two fields to a table
function addpost($userid, $post, $mylink) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post) VALUES ('$userid', '$post')";
  $result = mysqli_query($mylink, $sql;
  echo "done";
}

// then call it
addpost($userid, $post, $mylink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things

Values should be

```
VALUES('". $variable1 ."', '". $variable2. "');";
```

You can't quote variables in sql queries like regular strings. They are special. Also, you are missing a semi-colon at the end of your query. Notice I did this.

```
);";
```

The first semicolon is for the query, the second semicolon is for the php.

Second, your missing a )

```
$result = mysqli_query($mylink, $sql;\
```

should be

```
$result = mysqli_query($mylink, $sql);
```

Hope this helps, and welcome to stackoverflow!